# Is it possible to deserialize System.Text.Encoding class from JSON to code in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class, that I return as a JSON object through my Web API controller.

```
public class ModelClass
{
   public string QueryString {get; set;}
   public Encoding Encoding {get; set;}

   public BankLinkModel(string queryString , Encoding encoding)
   {
      this.QueryString = queryString ;
      this.Encoding = encoding;
   }
}
```

But when I try to deserialize this model in another application(that made an API CALL) with my code:

```
var responseFromApi = ApiClient.get(string.Format("some/magic/url?id={0}", "663"));
var query = responseFromApi.Content.ReadAsAsync<ModelClass>().Result;
```

I get an error:

> *Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.*

This is because `System.Text.Encoding` is an abstract class. Is there a way for me to deserialize `System.Text.Encoding` class ?

Comment: The content's encoding should be set on the appropriate HTTP header, *not* passed as a parameter.

Comment: How are you returning the results? Web API should take care of encoding and codepage automatically

Comment: All our requests are encoded with UTF-8, but for this precise request, i need to get the encoding class, because i'll be making another request, to a 3rd party application, that needs not UTF-8 encoding, but a special one(not a standart)

Comment: Then send a different `Accept-Charset` header with *that* request. Web API checks this header to determine the character set of the response. What character set are you using? Web API can handle almost all encodings, unless it's a newly invented one. Even then, the compliant way is to set `Accept-Charset` and check its value in your controller's method. This will ensure your API works with any client

Comment: The same question is [answered in S/O](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16866758/969278) previously. Hope it helps.

Comment: @saritas your provided link, does not work for my problem, since I need the WHOLE object, not just a fiew of its fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of serializing the `Encoding` instance, you could serialize the `Encoding.EncodingName` property and call `Encoding.GetEncoding(name)` method to create an instance when deserializing.

Comment: Could you explain more ? What do you mean by Encoding Name ? is it Encoding.BodyName, Encoding.HeaderName ?

Comment: Better yet, set the appropriate  response headers. BTW, Web API should set these automatically if the correct response call was made. Why send the encoding at all?

Comment: @SomeGuy I should have made it clear. It is `Encoding.EncodingName` property.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I should admit that I have very little knowledge about web programming. My answer is based on question "how to serialize an encoding". I appreciate if you can write up your own answer describing the right way..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the answer is too vague for an answer - either the OP doesn't know that Web API handles encoding/decoding, or wants to send an encoding name as a parameter that has nothing to do with the content itself. Or the OP uses an encoding that isn't supported by Web API/.NET (hard to believe)

Comment: Sadly passing Encoding.EncodingName did not work for me. I received an error: 'Baltic (Windows)' is not a supported encoding name.

Comment: EncodingName doesn't work. `Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.UTF8.EncodingName)` threw an exception: 'Unicode (UTF-8)' is not a supported encoding name. Better use CodePage property.

Answer (score 0):

Sriram Sakthivel's answer did not end up working (see comments), but the basic idea behind serializing a different property is the right way to go.

Instead of using `Encoding.EncodingName`, serialize `Encoding.WebName`. `Encoding.GetEncoding( string name )` accepts the values from the `WebName` property:

> The code page name of the preferred encoding. Any value returned by the WebName property is valid. Possible values are listed in the Name column of the table that appears in the Encoding class topic.

So the deserialization becomes `Encoding.GetEncoding( "utf-8" )`.